# WooCommerce | AJAX | Product Pagination | Help me implement Ajax Pagination

Tags: wp-query, theme-development, loop, ajax

Im struggling to find a good resource on implementing my own AJAX product pagination onto products within the WooCommerce shop loop.

Please can someone guide me on how is best to load more products without the page reloading.

I have previously been able to successfully load more posts and filter posts. However, have never had to do this to products.

It is my understanding I will need a function in functions.php. Linked up to the paginated products on the shop front page.

Ideally this functionality won't be limited to just the store front shop loop, but will carry over to search results pages.

So far I have tried unsuccessfully maybe 10 other resources and a couple plug-ins. All of which I feel are bulky, poorly documented or have to be paid for within the plug-ins.

**EDIT:** This is updated with my current attempt (I am trying to use as much of the inbuilt functionality of WordPress as possible):

Here is a starting point of the files I wish to manipulate. Please help me change them to create:

**ARCHIVE-PRODUCT.PHP** (Creates my shop loop, adds pagination to the bottom):

```
<?php
/**
 * @see https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.4.0
 */

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header();

if ( have_posts() ) { ?>

    <div id="product-loop"> 

        <?php
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        woocommerce_product_loop_start();
        if ( wc_get_loop_prop( 'total' ) ) {
            while ( have_posts() ) {
                the_post();
                do_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop' );
                wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
            }
        }
        woocommerce_product_loop_end();
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );

        ?>

    </div>

    <?php

} else {
    do_action( 'woocommerce_no_products_found' );
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );

get_footer();
```

**PAGINATION.PHP** (Amended to include buttons with text for previous / next):

```
<?php
/**
 * Pagination - Show numbered pagination for catalog pages
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/loop/pagination.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 3.3.1
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

$total   = isset( $total ) ? $total : wc_get_loop_prop( 'total_pages' );
$current = isset( $current ) ? $current : wc_get_loop_prop( 'current_page' );
$base    = isset( $base ) ? $base : esc_url_raw( str_replace( 999999999, '%#%', remove_query_arg( 'add-to-cart', get_pagenum_link( 999999999, false ) ) ) );
$format  = isset( $format ) ? $format : '';

if ( $total <= 1 ) {
    return;
}
?>
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <?php
        echo paginate_links( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_pagination_args', array( // WPCS: XSS ok.
            'base'         => $base,
            'format'       => $format,
            'add_args'     => false,
            'current'      => max( 1, $current ),
            'total'        => $total,
            'prev_text'    => '<div id="previous">Previous</div>',
            'next_text'    => '<div id="next">Next</div>',
            'type'         => 'plain',
            'end_size'     => 0,
            'mid_size'     => 0,
        ) ) );
    ?>
</nav>
```

**PAGINATION OUTPUT** (What we have to work with to trigger the AJAX pagination):

```
<nav class="woocommerce-pagination">
    <a class="prev page-numbers" href="https://example.com/">
        <div id="previous">Previous</div>
    </a>
    <span aria-current="page" class="page-numbers current">2</span><!-- CURRENT PAGE -->
    <span class="page-numbers dots">…</span><!-- CSS CHANGES THIS TO ' of ' -->
    <a class="page-numbers" href="https://example.com/?sf_paged=24">24</a><!-- TOTAL PAGES -->
    <a class="next page-numbers" href="https://example.com/?sf_paged=3">
        <div id="next">Next</div>
    </a>
</nav>
```

**PAGINATION-STYLES** (Stylesheet alters appearance to only show Previous (if applicable), current page number, total page number, Next (if applicable)):

```
/* Pagination */
.woocommerce-pagination {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
    #previous,
    #next {
        margin: 0 20px;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -moz-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        outline: 0;
        cursor: pointer;
        border: none;
        background-color: inherit;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 16px;
        color: #007dbe;
        webkit-transition: all 0.7s;
        transition: all 0.7s;
    }
    #previous {
        margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    }
    #next {
        margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
        #previous:hover,
        #next:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }

        #previous:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            margin-right: 5px;
            background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/blue-chevvy-left.svg');
            background-size: contain;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
        #next:after {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            width: 16px;
            height: 16px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            background-image: url('/wp-content/uploads/2020/01/blue-chevvy-right.svg');
        }
            .page-numbers {
                display: none;
            }
            .prev.page-numbers,
            .next.page-numbers,
            .page-numbers.current,
            .page-numbers.dots,
            .page-numbers.dots ~ .page-numbers {
                display: inline-block;
            }
                .page-numbers.dots {
                    width: 20px;
                    visibility: hidden;
                }
                    .page-numbers.dots:after {
                        content: ' of ';
                        visibility: visible;
                        position: absolute;
                        top: 50%;
                        left: 50%;
                        -ms-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                        -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
                    }
                .page-numbers.dots ~ .page-numbers {
                    color: #007dbe;
                }
                    .page-numbers.dots ~ .page-numbers:hover {
                        text-decoration: underline;
                    }
/* END Pagination */
```

**PAGINATION AJAX FUNCTION** | **FUNCTIONS.PHP** (This is where I need a pro's opinion, how can I trigger the pagination AJAX function using the links created in my pagination. I assume this will sit within the functions.php):

```
/* Custom Product Pagination */
function custom_product_pagination_function(){
    $args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'products',
        'posts_per_page'    => 9
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $query->have_posts() ) :
        while( $query->have_posts() ): $query->the_post();

            echo 'Product goes here'; 

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else :
        echo 'No posts found';
    endif;

    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_customproductpagination', 'custom_product_pagination_function');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_customproductpagination', 'custom_product_pagination_function');
/* END Custom Product Pagination */
```

**Please can someone help me write a trigger for the custom_product_pagination_function() based on the inputs on the pagination.php output & to generate the correct products within the function itself, lastly to return the value to the product loop with updated pagination values for the next click.**

I have spent a full day researching and bashing code together making zero progress :c

Massive thanks to all contributors, Jason.